# Strange Rendering Performance

Tags: wpf, performance, rendering

I want to do some rendering in WPF so that I found the hints in MSDN which suggest to use the light-weight DrawingVisual to make a rendering object (e.g. Triangle)

Whenever a property (e.g. color, coordinates) of the rendering is changed, it will render again.
(e.g. RenderOpen(); drawingContext.Draw(.......) ........)

Then I replace the rendering object with UIElement instead of DrawingVisual for the base class with other the same.
And I found that I only render one time no matter how I change the property. Still, I call InvalidateVisual() whenever a property is changed.

Eventually, I found that the rendering performance is much better than DrawingVisual.

Is it the truth?